# How to delete the satellite image that is outside the plot on the map

Tags: r, mapping, mask

I have to produce a large number of maps, each representing a farmer's plot. With my attached script I get a map where the satellite image appears with the outline of the plots, but I would like everything outside the plot not to appear (whether there is a mask on this area or it is made completely transparent). I can't find the solution, can any of you help me?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIx0A.jpg)

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(ggmap)
library(rgdal)
library(readxl)
library(XML)
library(sf)
library(cowplot)

# Set working directory to folder containing GPX files and Excel file
setwd("D:/Mes Donnees/R/Plant Health/aidecoop")


# Get list of GPX file names in working directory
gpx_files <- list.files(pattern = "\\.gpx$")
ggmap::register_google(key = "AIzaSyAL2uJOi7PcVKxB8EjOWJIBXxqSF7R-Nwo")

# Loop through GPX files and plot maps for each parcelle
for (i in 1:length(gpx_files)) {
  
  # Extract parcelle name from file name
  parcelle <- gsub(".gpx", "", gpx_files[i])
  
  # Read in GPX file
  gpx_data <- st_read(gpx_files[i], layer = "track_points")
  # Extract longitude and latitude data from GEOMETRY column
  coords <- st_coordinates(gpx_data)
  # Create a matrix of coordinates
  mat_coords <- as.matrix(coords)
  # Create a Polygon object from the matrix of coordinates
  track_poly <- Polygon(mat_coords)
  # Create a SpatialPolygons object from the Polygon object
  track_polygons <- SpatialPolygons(Srl = list(Polygons(list(track_poly), ID = "track")), proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
  # convert the polygon to a projected coordinate system with units in meters
  utm_zone <- floor((mean(st_coordinates(gpx_data)[, 1]) + 180) / 6) + 1
  # create an sf object from SpatialPolygons object
  track_sf <- st_as_sf(track_polygons)
  track_poly_proj <- st_transform(track_sf, CRS(paste0("+proj=utm +zone=", utm_zone)))
  
  # calculate the area of the polygon in hectares
  area <- st_area(track_poly_proj) / 10000
  
  # Add area to map title
  title <- paste("Carte de la parcelle ", parcelle, " (", round(area, 2), " ha)")
  
  # Extract longitude and latitude data from GEOMETRY column
  coords <- st_coordinates(gpx_data$geometry)
  
  # Add longitude and latitude columns to data frame
  gpx_data$lon <- coords[,1]
  gpx_data$lat <- coords[,2]
  
  # Get bounding box of GPX data
  bbox <- st_bbox(gpx_data)
  
  # Calculate center and zoom level for Google Map
  center_lat <- mean(bbox[c("ymin", "ymax")])
  center_lon <- mean(bbox[c("xmin", "xmax")])
  delta_lat <- abs(bbox["ymax"] - bbox["ymin"])
  delta_lon <- abs(bbox["xmax"] - bbox["xmin"])
  delta_diag <- sqrt(delta_lat^2 + delta_lon^2)
  
  # Plot map
  map <- ggmap::get_map(location = c(lon = center_lon, lat = center_lat), zoom = 18, maptype = "hybrid")
  
  # Plot map
  ggmap(map) +
    geom_polygon(data = gpx_data, aes(x = lon, y = lat), color = "white",alpha=0.5, size = 1) +
    labs(title = title, x = "Longitude", y = "Latitude") +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
    theme(legend.position = "none")+
    coord_fixed(1 / cos(mean(gpx_data$lat) * pi / 180))+
    theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 14),
          axis.text = element_text(size = 12))
  
  # Save map to file
  ggsave(paste0(parcelle, ".png"), width = 8, height = 8, dpi = 72)
  
}
```

This is the type of image I would like to get automatically with the script.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAnL8.jpg)